# DropDownList filter of GridView not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

In the web-based application that I am working on it, I have two GridViews.There is a DropDownList above the first GridView which is used for filter the suggestions based on the division of the user. This DropDownList is not working anymore after putting the second GridView inside the UpdatePanel control and I don't know why or what is the relation between this and this. Any idea?

Everything was working fine before adding the second GridView inside the UpdatePanel control, **but now the filter for filtering the suggestions in the first GridView is not working. Any idea? Any help please?**

My ASP.NET Code:

```
<strong> Division </strong>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDivision" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
        AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="sqlDataSourceDivision" 
        DataTextField="DivisionShortcut" DataValueField="DivisionShortcut"  
        Width="175px" EnableViewState="False">
        <asp:ListItem Value="%">All</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>    
    <br />  <br />  
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                        DataKeyNames="ID" 
                        width="950px" CssClass="mGrid"
                        AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" 
                        RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
                        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <HeaderStyle Font-Bold = "true" ForeColor="Black" Height="20px"/> 
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False"  ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"  SortExpression="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="Username"  SortExpression="Username" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DivisionShortcut" HeaderText="Division"  SortExpression="DivisionShortcut" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server" 
                          DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2"
                          Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#006666" 
                          AppendDataBoundItems="false" 
                          DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="ID" 
                          AutoPostBack="true" 
                          OnDataBound="DropDownList_DataBound" 
                          OnSelectedIndexChanged ="DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.ID, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Title, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Description, dbo.employee.Name, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username, dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut FROM dbo.employee INNER JOINdbo.SafetySuggestionsLog ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username INNER JOIN dbo.Divisions ON dbo.employee.DivisionCode = dbo.Divisions.SapCode"
                      FilterExpression="[DivisionShortcut] like '{0}%'">
                      <FilterParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlDivision" 
                           Name="DivisionShortcut" PropertyName="SelectedValue" 
                           Type="String" />
                    </FilterParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <%--For the DropDownList--%>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server"
           ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
           SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [SafetySuggestionsStatus]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>  
        <%--Filtering by Division--%>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDataSourceDivision" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [DivisionShortcut] FROM [Divisions]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"> 
           <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlDivision" 
                 EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
           </Triggers>
           <ContentTemplate>
           <br />
           <p><h3><b><u>PMOD Divisions' Safety Suggestions List</u></b></h3>
               <p></p><br />
               <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                  <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="mGrid" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                      DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" >
                      <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                      <HeaderStyle Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Black" Height="20px" />
                      <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SubmittedMonth" HeaderText="Month Submitted" ReadOnly="True"  SortExpression="SubmittedMonth" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="DivisionShortcut"  HeaderText="Division" SortExpression="DivisionShortcut" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Username" HeaderText="NetworkID"  SortExpression="Username" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
                       </Columns>
                       <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                     </asp:GridView>
                  </asp:Panel>
                  <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT LEFT(DATENAME(month, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.DateSubmitted), 3) + '-' + DATENAME(year, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.DateSubmitted)  AS SubmittedMonth, dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username, dbo.employee.Name, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Title,  dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Description, dbo.SafetySuggestionsType.Type, dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus.Status FROM  dbo.Divisions INNER JOIN dbo.employee ON dbo.Divisions.SapCode = dbo.employee.DivisionCode INNER JOIN dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username INNER JOIN dbo.SafetySuggestionsType ON dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.TypeID = dbo.SafetySuggestionsType.ID INNER JOIN dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus ON dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.StatusID = dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus.ID WHERE     (DATEDIFF(month, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.DateSubmitted, GETDATE()) &lt; 3) ORDER BY dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.DateSubmitted DESC">
                   </asp:SqlDataSource>
     <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" OnClick="btnPrint_Click" Text="Print" />
     <p></p></p>    
   </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code-Behind:

```
protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["ctrl"] = Panel1;
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(GridView2, GridView2.GetType(), "onclick", "window.open('Print.aspx','PrintMe','height=400px,width=800px,scrollbars=1');", true);
    }    
    int i = 1;
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = i.ToString();
            i++;    
        }
    }  
    protected void DropDownList_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            ((DropDownList)sender).Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", ""));
    }    
    protected void DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        int suggestionStatus = int.Parse(ddl.SelectedValue);
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.NamingContainer;
        string strID = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex]["ID"].ToString();
        int ID = Int32.Parse(strID);
        //For inserting the status in the database
        string connString = "Data Source=localhost\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=psspdbTest;Integrated Security=True";
        string updateCommand = "UPDATE SafetySuggestionsLog  SET [StatusID] = @StatusID WHERE [ID] = @ID";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(updateCommand, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatusID", suggestionStatus);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }    
        GridView2.DataBind();    
    }
```

Comment: in the selected index changed event its showing `GridView2.DataBind();`

Comment: I did not get you. Could you please explain it more?

Comment: You mention as your top dropdown not working whereas there is no relevant code for the same, so not sure as what your problem is !

Comment: **is not working** doesn't help much, so please add details of error if any or the behaviour

Comment: There is no error shown. All what I have, is the first dropdownlist with id=ddlDivision doesn't work anymore and this is happened after adding the second GridView inside the UpdatePanel control.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try to put your DropDownList inside the updatepanel and add the postback trigger to the DropDownList also

Answer (score 0):

The gridview you want to populate should be in your Update Panel

---

You should also consider `UpdateMode` in Update panel as it is `Always by default`

---

You may be missing the binding of `gridview 1` in `DropDownList handler`

Comment: He has specified the Gridview2 DataSource in the markup for the gridview: DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4".

Answer (score 0):

I think what has happened is that once you set the ddlDivision as a trigger for your UpdatePanel, it will no longer do a normal postback. Instead, it will cause the UpdatePanel partial postback process. Since your Gridview1 is not included in the UpdatePanel's `ContentTemplate`, it will no longer be updated after a postback. That's the way UpdatePanel's work -- they only return changes to items inside them, and not other items on the page.

Before you put the UdpatePanel with the dropdown as a trigger, the AutoPostback setting on the ddlDivision would have caused your **whole page** to get refreshed, and your gridview would be filtered because your datasource uses the ddl as a parameter.

Comment: So what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: As you know you have a dropdown trigger in update panel. On selecting the record in dropdown. you will get updations only in gridview 2. In order to get the gridview 1 updates. Keep it in same update panel.

Comment: As Pankaj says, you could put Gridview1 in the update panel as well, but at that point, is there any real use in having an update panel, since the whole page is basically getting updated? You could just remove the update panel completely, unless there's a good reason to have it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you added a ScriptManager?

Anyway, looking at your code, I can see you added **AsyncPostBackTrigger** for **ddlDivision** but you haven't yet created **SelectedIndexChanged** event for **ddlDivision**, try this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDivision" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="sqlDataSourceDivision" DataTextField="DivisionShortcut" 
DataValueField="DivisionShortcut" Width="175px" EnableViewState="False" 

OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDivision_SelectedIndexChanged">

    <asp:ListItem Value="%">All</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and then of course, add your code behind to handle the event.